# Why are my badge numbers much lower on Meta SO?

Tags: discussion, badges, meta

I am very new to Meta. I can see my reputation points are the same on both SO and Meta, but my badge numbers do not match..

These are the badges I have for each site:

- Main Site: 3 silver badges and 26 bronze badges
- Meta SO: 1 silver badge and 2 bronze badges

Why do I see such a huge difference?

Comment: Meta is a different site to Stack Overflow, so your badge count doesn't transfer.

Comment: Why remove all the tags on your question? If you were trying to get less attention.... This post was already falling off the "Active" tab, you really just bumped it up. If you're trying to get rid of it because of downvotes, really, don't worry about them- Downvotes are different on Meta. Check out the "What's Meta?" page in the [help] to read up about it, if you haven't already.

Comment: Actually I want to delete my question as I don’t like people simply downvote without a valid reason. It’s not like I got down votes and I am deleting. I can’t accept blind down votes. Hence I want to delete. I still want to delete Even I am not much impacted with downvotes.

Comment: In this case, people are likely downvoting for lack of research- Because it honestly could've been found with a good search. Your last post, the one you already deleted, was likely downvoted because, as I said above, downvoting is different on Meta. You posted what boiled down to a combination rant and a feature-request. The feature-request part has been hit on before, and rants, even light ones like yours, almost always get downvoted to smithereens. (Of course, at the same time, you missed out on answers by deleting so quickly. I was writing one myself.)

Comment: The reason most people won't comment on "research effort" downvotes is because it's already explained on this page- In the tooltip for downvotes. Hover over that, and you'll see _"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."_

Comment: Thanks for your time in explaining Kendra. I don’t like downvoting without a reason But SO allows people to downvote without reasons required. But why then the question gets answers and answers gets upvotes.

Comment: Yeah, I hit on that a few times in the answer I was writing for your deleted post- When you've been around (on meta) long enough, you start to understand why it is that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta doesn't have its own rep, so that's why you see it being the same (there might be a slight caching delay sometimes though, so be aware of that).

When it comes to badges, badges on the main site do not carry over to meta, so this is entirely expected.